# Error when starting JBoss sever , I can't run localhost:8080

Tags: java, jboss

HI，I'm new to managing a JBoss server, and everything was fine until 3 hours ago, but I couldn't log in to localhost:8080 anymore. standalone displayed some errors. Could anyone help me clarify what the problems are?

```
Java HotSpot 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256M; support was removed in 8.0
18:30:09,393 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.3.6.Final-redhat-1
18:30:09,483 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.1.5.Final-redhat-1
18:30:09,518 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015899: JBoss EAP 6.4.0.GA (AS 7.5.0.Final-redhat-21) starting
18:30:09,714 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015956: Caught exception during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: JBAS014676: Failed to parse configuration
        at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:141) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:330) [jboss-as-server-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:263) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_251]
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '1' (code 49) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedChar(StreamScanner.java:639)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2052)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1134)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextTag(BasicStreamReader.java:1157)
        at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:67) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final-redhat-3.jar:1.1.0.Final-redhat-3]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:133) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        ... 3 more

18:30:09,718 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015957: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
```

Comment: Looks like there is something wrong with your `standalone.xml` file. Did you edit it manually?

Comment: Thanks, just like you said it's the problem, It's been edited somehow.